# Are there any set rules for string limits in Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

On Twitter it's clear - 140 utf-8 chars, no html.
Does Facebook have clear set of rules about what is allowed in strings posted to wall via API?

I am referring to this API: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

I did some experiments and it looks like the content of "message" cannot contain any html tags - they will all be converted to html entities.
The content of "description" can contain bold and italic tag but the rest of the html tags are completely removed - not even converted to html entities - just removed along with the values of tags.

I still have no idea as to the maximum lengths of string allowed in "message", "description" and "caption". What formatting tags are allowed?

Does anyone know if Facebook clearly stated the limits for those strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any "*official*" notation about this, which is one more "flaw" to add to their documentation!

I hope someone can prove me wrong! (*I really do!*)